# Getting token from Spotify using node-schedule and redirect

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, node-schedule

Logging in and getting access token on client

```
const Login = () => {
  return (
    <>
     <button>
       <a href=http://localhost:3001/login`}>Login</a>
     </button>
    </>
  )
}
```

next, redirecting to server using the following code

```
const router = express.Router()

router.get('/login', async (req, res) => {
  res.redirect(loginUrl)
})
```

```
loginUrl = `https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?client_id=${process.env.CLIENT_ID}&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3001/callback`
```

```
router.get('/callback', async (req, res) => {
  const code = req.query.code || null

// rest of the code where tokens are handled
}
```

I want to schedule couple of my services(using other spotify APIs) on server to run automatically once per day, however they require access token. So my idea was to create a job to trigger the `/login` and redirect to `/callback` and get the token for further processing.

How can I achieve this by calling it from the server? So far I tried axios but it can't handle the redirection and I haven't figure out how to setup any http service to do it automatically within the job yet, using `node-schedule`

Comment: You can't. This is the OAuth login flow, and that requires user interaction. The redirect needs to happen inside a user's browser, because only there Spotify can check, who that user actually is. You'll need to perform this step once, in the way it is intended to - and then store the resulting token, so that you can use it for your server-side API calls. And if the token expired, you will have to involve the user again.

Comment: So you're basically saying there's no way to automate this login action without involving user clicking the button...

Comment: Not for a user access token, no. Not sure if Spotiy provides any other kinds of token, that could be used for such background processes, you'd have to check their docs.

Comment: It is possible if you can log in once. The thing you need is a refresh token. You can read more about it in the [Authorization Code Flow](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization/code-flow/) documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To accomplish what you want, you need to make something that can request an access token and a refresh token. When the access token is expired, the server can request a new access token and a new refresh token with the refresh token.
You can read more about it in the [Authorization Code Flow](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization/code-flow/) documentation.

Comment: OK so my understanding is that for the first time I need to log-in manually, store the encrypted refresh token somewhere and then set up the node-schedule to run once per day as I want it to, always picking up the refresh token that would trigger the axios post method using the refresh token in order to receive fresh access token.

Comment: @smoothlikebutter yes, that's correct